# The symbol 'PDEContentGetNumElemsSELPROTO' is not defined

Tags: c++, plugins, adobe

I am doing adobe acrobat plug-in development has encountered a problem.

My development environment:

```
windows 7 64-bit
visual studio 2008
```

And installed adobe acrobat plug-in development support tools AcroXPIWizInstaller.
I successfully created this plug-in project, when I use "PDEContentGetNumElems' problems.
Error message:

> "error C2065: the 'PDEContentGetNumElemensSELPROTO': undeclared
>   identifier"

In this method, I right-click -> "Go To Definition"
I find the file 'PERCalls.h' the 'PDEContentGetNumElemensSELPROTO' I can not Go to Definition.
Get the error message:

> "The symbol 'PDEContentGetNumElemsSELPROTO' is not defined."

Comment: You _do_ include the header file in the source?

Comment: Yes, I was able to find the header files, I use Adobe official SDK package.I can sample programs provided by the official, but I use the tools provided by the new project will not be able to?